# List comprehension for independent loops

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I'm trying to use a list comprehension for two not nested for loops. This is my solution without list comprehension:

```
import numpy as np
n_steps = 20
x_steps = [int(i) for i in np.linspace(10, 60, n_steps)]
y_steps = [int(i) for i in np.linspace(25, 150, n_steps)]
steps = [(x_steps[i], y_steps[i]) for i in range(len(x_steps))]
```

As you can see I want `steps = [(10, 25), (13, 31), ...]`

Is there an elegant and pythonic way to do it in one line with list comprehension or similar? In my mind I have something like this:

```
steps = [(int(x), int(j)) for x in np.linspace(10, 60, n_steps) and j in np.linspace(25, 150, n_steps)]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to iterate through two lists in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663807/how-to-iterate-through-two-lists-in-parallel). Assuming you are not aware of `zip`, a naive approach would be to collapse names: `steps = [(int(np.linspace(10, 60, n_steps)[i]), int(np.linspace(25, 150, n_steps)[i])) for i in range(len(np.linspace(10, 60, n_steps)))]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `zip`

```
import numpy as np
n_steps = 20
steps = [(int(i),int(j)) for i,j in zip(np.linspace(10, 60, n_steps),np.linspace(25, 150, n_steps))]
```

Comment: Coz, the `float`  to `int` conversion is also taking place.

Answer (score 1):

Zip is your answer :)

```
list(zip(x_steps, y_steps))
```